# Как выделить из текста имена? C#

Tags: c#, строки

> В функцию поступает текст в виде строки (производной длины т.к. загружается с файла). Из этой строки нужно выбрать все имена по типу "Фамилия Имя Отчество" и "Фамилия И. О.".

Как я понимаю поиск выполняется по определенному расположению точек и заглавных букв, а для этого нужно разбить весь текст на какие-то элементы.

Как это сделать и на что лучше разбивать?

И регулярные выражения использовать запрещено.

Comment: Что у вас уже получилось? Добавте ваш  код прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

> нужно разбить весь текст на какие-то элементы. Как это сделать и на
>   что лучше разбивать?

на слова наверное (=__=) например с помощью [Метода String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
String[] words = input.Split(new Char[]{'\s','\t','\r','\n'}, 
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
//разделители: пробел, табуляция, переносы строки; отбрасывать пустые.
```

вам осталось перебрать тройки идущих подряд слов на соответствие вашему шаблону, а готового кода не будет :).